# Java Gson Exclude fields during serialization

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I have a `ConfigInstance` class which contains a `password` and a `password_hash`.
Now I want to serialize the object using gson but exclude the `password` field.

```
public class ConfigInstance {
    public String database_address;
    public int database_port;
    public String database_user;

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    private String database_pass;
    public String database_pass_hash;

    public String GetPass() { return database_pass; }

    public void Encrypt() { /* Creates the hash before serializing*/ }

    public void Decrypt() { /* Creates the password after deserializing */}
}
```

As you can see, I have tried using `@Expose(serialize = false)` but it doesn't seem to do anything. Also I already set the field to private since I figured that this would "override" the `@Expose`

but running following code:

```
private void toFile(File file, ConfigInstance map) {
    map.Encrypt();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String jsonConfig = gson.toJson(map);
    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(jsonConfig);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error exporting config: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

still results in the following file content without Errors:

```
{
  "database_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "database_port": 1521,
  "database_user": "test",
  "database_pass": "test1234",
  "database_pass_hash": "B9FE2C011B59F0D0D383D70073E48A19"
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? I am pretty clueless right now and would appreciate any help since [THIS](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/) doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have edit access to the object's class to be serialized, you can use annotation 'Exposed' as mentioned by @bosco. If you don't have edit access, that is, if it's in an external lib, you can use other approaches like the ones listed here https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In order to get this result, you need to annotate all the fields with the `@Expose`:

```
public class ConfigInstance {

    @Expose
    public String database_address;
    @Expose
    public int database_port;
    @Expose
    public String database_user;

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    private String database_pass;
    @Expose
    public String database_pass_hash;
```

And configure Gson to only expose fields that are annotated and ignore the rest as shown in the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Then, you'll get:

```
{
  "database_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "database_port": 1521,
  "database_user": "test",
  "database_pass_hash": "B9FE2C011B59F0D0D383D70073E48A19"
}
```

Also, when deserialising the string you'll still have the password attribute as well.

---

Still, you have the possibility to configure a [Gson Serializer](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 25):

This is another way.

serialization:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("fieldName");
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();
```

deserialization:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("fieldName");
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();
```

Comment: So helpful way!

Comment: Kotlin: `return f.name == "fieldName"`

Answer (score 21):

If you like particular field not be serialized give it a transient keyword

```
private transient String database_pass;
```

visit https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects for more information

Comment: indeed, I tried this aswell, but the problem is that transient fields are completely ignored by Gson, also when deserializing. So in case that the passwords gets modified in-file, the database_pass field wouldnt be assigned when deserializing,

Answer (score 11):

@utkusonmez
This answer works albeit the method mentioned is wrong.
It should be using 'addSerializationExclusionStrategy' instead of 'addDeserializationExclusionStrategy'

So the answer would look like

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("fieldName");
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();

gson.toJson(*OBJ_TO_SERIALIZE*))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to disable only serialization or only deserialization, you can play with `@Expose` annotation's attributes, e.g.:

```
@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)
```

Default option is true, so deserialize is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2):

It's a late answer but it may help someone.

You only have to do the `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)` or just what you want.

If you have `serialize` and `deserialize` `true` its not nesseccary to have `@Expose` at all.

Create this Class:

```
import com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy;
import com.google.gson.FieldAttributes;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class NoModuleExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    private final boolean deserialize;

    public NoModuleExclusionStrategy(boolean isdeserialize) {
        deserialize = isdeserialize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
        return !(field.getAnnotation(Expose.class) == null || (deserialize ? field.getAnnotation(Expose.class).deserialize() : field.getAnnotation(Expose.class).serialize()));
    }

}
```

and then build Gson with GsonBuilder

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new NoModuleExclusionStrategy(false))
.addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new NoModuleExclusionStrategy(true))
.create();
```

Your ConfigInstance Class will look like follows

```
{
  "database_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "database_port": 1521,
  "database_user": "test",
  "database_pass_hash": "B9FE2C011B59F0D0D383D70073E48A19"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution with just one line of code, without any @Expose annotation or exclusion strategy.

The default behaviour that is implemented in Gson is that [null object fields are ignored](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support). So, all you need to do is set the password field to null before serializing.

```
map.setPassword(null); // or map.password = null;
String jsonConfig = gson.toJson(map); // This won't serialize null password field
```