# Spring and Gson - Expose fields only on certain conditions

Tags: java, spring, serialization, gson, spring-json

I'm using Spring with Gson to object serialization.

I have model objects that use `@Expose` annotation e.g.:

```
public class Zone {
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @Expose
    private List<String> longList;

    private String someIrrelevantVar;
}
```

I'm have 2 controllers which serves `Zone` objects list to user e.g.:

```
@RestController
class ZoneController {
    @GetMapping(value = "fullData")
    List<Zone> getFullZones() {
        return zoneService.getZones();
    }
}

@RestController
class SimpleZoneController {
    @GetMapping(value = "simpleData")
    List<Zone> getSimpleZones() {
        return zoneService.getZones();
    }
}
```

The problem is `List<String> longList` var - it usually has a lot of entries (`String` is only example, in code it could be complex object).

In my `getFullZones()` I want to serve to user zones with this `longList` but in `getSimpleZones()` I want ot serve zones without `longList` (it's not used in any way on the client side).

How to do that?

I could iterate list with zones and set `longList` to null but it's not very elegant solution.

I'm setting up `Spring` to use `Gson` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(createGsonHttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
    private GsonHttpMessageConverter createGsonHttpMessageConverter() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                //.registerTypeAdapter - register some deserializers
                .create();
        GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        gsonConverter.setGson(gson);

        return gsonConverter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class ZoneSimple and extend another class Zone extends ZoneSimple. Move the @Expose from fields to methods.

In the base class the method has no annotation. In the Zone the method is annotated.

Alternatively you can add a ProxyZone class which keeps zone instance and delegates all the calls to the instance. Annotate the Proxy as you need.

Another way is

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("fieldName");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .create();
```

Got from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909205/java-gson-exclude-fields-during-serialization)

Comment: The `@Expose` is applicable only to fields, not methods. Could you explain solution with `ProxyZone`? How the third solution could work in my case?

Comment: Sorry I miss that @Expose is applied to fields only. Then you can try the `addSerializationExclusionStrategy` based approach

Comment: but how to use `ExclusionStrategy` in this case? I have only one instance of `Gson` (created in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`) and if I add there `ExclusionStrategy` for certain fields for `Zone` class it will effect anywhere. Or should I create new `Gson` instance in my `getSimpleZones()` method and add `ExclusionStrategy` there?

Comment: Create the GsonBuilder on fly rather than use autowired.

Comment: I didn't mean `@Autowired` Gson but Gson registered as `HttpMessageConverter` used by default when serializing any data

Comment: Then just create 2 different classes