# How do I deserialize an array of objects using gson and JsonWriter

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following classes:

```
public class MeetingCenter {
    private String name;
    private List<MeetingRoom> meetingRoomList;
}

public class MeetingRoom {
    private MeetingCenter meetingCenter;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private List<Reservation> reservationList;
}

public class Reservation {
    private MeetingRoom meetingRoom;
    private String owner;
}
```

And I want to create a JSON with following schema:

[image: Schema]

This method throws me an exception on the line where I call the toJson() method:

```
private static void exportToJson(List<MeetingCenter> mcs) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String data = gson.toJson(mcs);

    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("export.json"));
    writer.setIndent("    "); // set indent

    writer.beginObject(); // document start
    writer.name("schema").value("PLUS4U.EBC.MCS.MeetingRoom_Schedule_1.0");
    writer.name("uri").value("ues:UCL-BT:UCL.INF/DEMO_REZERVACE:EBC.MCS.DEMO/MR001/SCHEDULE");
    writer.name("data").value(data);

    writer.endObject(); // document end
    writer.close();
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:380)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:77)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeName(JsonWriter.java:614)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginArray(JsonWriter.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
    ....
```

Comment: Can you print the exception retrieved?

Comment: Without seeing the exception, my guess is the problem is in the cycle in your object structure: `MeetingRoom -> Reservation -> MeetingRoom`. You need to break the structure somehow. For example instead of reference to the MeetingRoom in reservation, you may want to serialize only the code of the MeetingRoom.

Comment: I see, so I cant use gson for that, as long as I dont want to change they way Reservation class is implemented.

Comment: You can add some Gson annotations on the fields or if you cannot modify the sources(if it comes from a library for example), you can implement a serializer for the Reservation class. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-serialization-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Your objects all have references to their parents.

GSON takes looks at a `MeetingCenter` then tries to serialize its child `MeetingRoom`s. The `MeetingRoom`s have reference back to the `MeetingCenter`, so GSON goes around and around in circles until you get a stack overflow.

To fix this, you can make sure to only expose the children and not the parents. There are plenty of questions showing this already. See [Java Gson Exclude fields during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909205/java-gson-exclude-fields-during-serialization).

For example, your `Reservation` might look like this:

```
class Reservation {
    MeetingRoom meetingRoom;
    @Expose
    String owner;
}
```

I'll leave the rest up to you.

---

Also, you have a method call to `writer.endArray()` when you have not started an array. Remove that line.

```
writer.beginObject(); // document start
writer.name("schema").value("PLUS4U.EBC.MCS.MeetingRoom_Schedule_1.0");
writer.name("uri").value("ues:UCL-BT:UCL.INF/DEMO_REZERVACE:EBC.MCS.DEMO/MR001/SCHEDULE");
writer.name("data").value(data);

//writer.endArray(); removed
writer.endObject(); // document end
writer.close();
```

Comment: he says the exception is thrown before that

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I see. Then there were two problems. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The @Expose is the solution to avoid the stackoverflow exception but the statement

```
writer.name("data").value(data);
```

is not valide because the data will be enriched with escape char. For exampla you can have in the data field

```
"data": "{\"name\": \"center 1\" ... }"
```

so there can will be problems in the deserialize phase.

My implementation proposes a Container class for the MeetingCenter class where the schema and the URI can be configured.

```
/** Container class configures the schema and URI */
public class Container {
    @Expose
    private String schema;
    @Expose
    private String uri;
    @Expose
    private List<MeetingCenter> data;
}

public class Reservation {
    private MeetingRoom meetingRoom;
    @Expose
    private String owner;
}

public class MeetingRoom {
    private MeetingCenter meetingCenter;
    @Expose
    private String code;
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private List<Reservation> reservationList;
}

public class MeetingCenter {
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private List<MeetingRoom> meetingRoomList;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Container container = meetingCenterInitialization();

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        // it is necessary to avoid stackoverflow
        builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();

        Gson gson = builder.create();

        String jsonString = gson.toJson(container);
        System.out.println(jsonString);


        Container container1 = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Container.class);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n" + container1.getData().get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

The output of the main method is

```
{
  "schema": "PLUS4U.EBC.MCS.MeetingRoom_Schedule_1.0",
  "uri": "ues:UCL-BT:UCL.INF/DEMO_REZERVACE:EBC.MCS.DEMO/MR001/SCHEDULE",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "center name",
      "meetingRoomList": [
        {
          "code": "room 1",

         ...
```